# Convert a character into another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send some params to the backend.

```
   var params = $('#creationModal').serialize();
    console.log(params);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/create-flow/save?flowName=' + flowName + '&testCaseNames=' + testCaseNames + '&' + params
```

> console.log(params): params=506%2C77&params=sfa&params=sfasgags

The problem is that I get a string with `506,77,sfa,sfasgags` but the first value `506,77` is actually a float.

I just want to send the string separated by `|` instead of `,`. Is there a way to serialize this way?

Backend

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/create-flow/save" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveFlow(HttpSession session, @RequestParam("flowName") String flowName, @RequestParam("testCaseNames") String[] testCaseNames, @RequestParam(value = "params", required = false) String params) {
    String user = session.getAttribute("loggedUser").toString();
    return TestFlow.addFlow(flowName,testCaseNames, params,user);
}
```

Comment: parse to str and use `text.replace(',', '|')`

Comment: where?? If I do that in the backend I end up losing my float.

Comment: Can you show your html please?

Comment: <input name="params" id="param-EXPECTED_RATE_VALUE" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert the parameter for EXPECTED_RATE_VALUE">

Comment: @user9485152 it shoudn't be returning as 506,77 in the first place - you need to fix the original issue of the data

Comment: what are you talking about? There are some inputs with name params... I fill the values and serialize and send to the backend. just that

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle with your html and js code?

Comment: @user9485152 less racism please - and also, your data should be a float to begin with, before the serialization, you have an error in your code that allows the input to be XYZ,ABC when it should be XYZ.AB